# Multiple Docker Containers fails to properly run startup program

Tags: docker

I have a script that spawns multiple containers (from a single image) with the same mounted data volumes; and same startup command (but this command has different arguments/parameters). This command takes in a videofile and process it with specified set of parameters.

The script takes care of assigning which videofile and what parameters to give to a container. Each container only process 1 videofile with a single set of parameters. Writes its result in a data volume with a distinct filename, then finally exits.

Containers spawn as expected but only the 1st configuration on each videofile gets processed (e.g. vid1+config1 and vid2+config1). Other containers with different configurations (e.g. vid1+config2, vid1+config3, vid2+config2 etc) do not finish as expected - output file gets lost or not created at all

Here is the script that spawns the containers:

```
#!/bin/bash    
source "$1"
echo "DescriptorFile = ${DescriptorFile}"
echo "nCounter Config File = ${nCounterConfigFile}"
echo "HT_start = ${HT_start}"
echo "HT_end = ${HT_end}"
echo "HT_step = ${HT_step}"
echo "VideoDirectory = ${VideoDirectory}"
echo "VideoFileExtension = ${VideoFileExtension}"

CURR_DIR=$PWD
cd $VideoDirectory
VideoDirectory=${VideoDirectory}
currHT=$HT_start
for f in $VideoDirectory*$VideoFileExtension
do
currHT=$HT_start

    while [ $(echo " $currHT <= $HT_end" | bc -l)  == 1 ]   
    do
           echo "Current active HT = $currHT"
            ##spawn containers
             (docker run -t \
                -v ${VideoDirectory}:/home/validationVideos \
                -v $CURR_DIR/modelFiles:/home/modelFiles \
                -v $CURR_DIR/nCounterConfigFiles:/home/nCounterConfigFiles \
                -v $CURR_DIR/Results:/home/results \
                    validationdocker /home/start.sh \
               -f /home/validationVideos/${f##*/} -c 
               /home/nCounterConfigFiles/$nCounterConfigFile -m 
               /home/modelFiles/$DescriptorFile -h $currHT -l 
               /home/dough_$CURR_CONTAINERS -w 0 -d  $CURR_CONTAINERS && 
               CURR_CONTAINERS=`expr $CURR_CONTAINERS - 1`) & 

            CURR_CONTAINERS="$(echo $CURR_CONTAINERS + 1| bc)"

        currHT="$(echo $currHT + $HT_step | bc)"
    done
 done

 exit
```

The usage of start.sh is 
"Usage: command <-f videofile -c configfile -m datModelfile -h htvalue -l saveDoughLocation -w boolIntShowWindow -d dockerID

Any leads would be greatly greatly appreciated! I am btw running docker 1.13.1  on ubuntu 16.04

Best,
Tom

---

[Here are the results of docker logs on the first Docker Container DocekrID_0. See the dough was created and process completed successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OE9zJ.png)

[On second run, dough was not created even though only 1 parameter changed and is absolutely valid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYvwi.png)

No notable entries in the results of docker events. I wanted to put the picture but I cant due to Stackoverflow limits

Comment: post `docker logs failing_container` and `docker events` while you launch all your containers

Comment: There @user2915097. I already posted the required info. Thanks for the quick reply. Also here is docker events https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B11Vdj6lfKioWlV4Um1BbmxHeVk